# Joda DateTime Format in Play 2.6 is not working

Tags: json, scala, datetime, playframework, jodatime

Trying to migrate my code to play 2.6
Everything is fine except the Format for DateTime type.

As part of the migration I did add the `play-json-joda` as dependency.

However, something like this:

```
case class GeoArea(id: Option[Int] = None,
                   continentId: Option[Int] = None,
                   countryId: Option[Int] = None,
                   code: String,
                   name: String,
                   discr: Discriminator.Value,
                   createdAt: DateTime = DateTime.now,
                   updatedAt: DateTime = DateTime.now,
                   deletedAt: Option[DateTime] = None,
                   createdBy: Option[String] = None,
                   updatedBy: Option[String] = None)
```

With format object defined as:

```
implicit lazy val geoAreaFormat: Format[GeoArea] = Json.format[GeoArea]
```

I am getting an error:

> No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for
>   org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.DateTime,
>   scala.Option[org.joda.time.DateTime] in the implicit scope (Hint: if
>   declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before) [error]
>   implicit lazy val geoAreaFormat: Format[GeoArea] =
>   Json.format[GeoArea]

What am I missing? What else do I need to have in scope to resolve that?

My imports look like this:

```
import driver.PGDriver.api._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.libs.json._
import slick.lifted.Tag
import model.GeoAreas.Discriminator
import converters.{JsonEnumeration, SlickEnumeration}
```

And they didn't change as during the migration, but these ones were enough for everything to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462673/how-to-use-joda-datetime-with-play-json
(also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509268/no-instance-of-play-api-libs-json-format-is-available-for-scala-iterablejava-la and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849424/no-instance-of-play-api-libs-json-format-is-available-for-models-accountstatus-i )

Comment: First one talks about play 2.3 which is a different story than 2.6.  The other two completely unrelated. There is a standard Format for Joda.DateTime. I probably don't know how to use it.

Comment: No, for example this answer says about 2.6 (it's from first of my links):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45440349/5249621

Comment: So, does it mean that in 2.6 I must define my own? There is no default implementation ?

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9):

In your build.sbt add this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json-joda_2.12" % "2.6.0"
```

then in file with your model import this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.JodaWrites._
import play.api.libs.json.JodaReads._
```

Comment: Yes it does! (Y)

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this inconvenience as well moving to the new library. You can work around it by creating an implicit format based on their new defaults.

```
implicit val dateFormat = new OFormat[DateTime] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DateTime] = JodaReads.DefaultJodaDateTimeReads.reads(json)
    override def writes(o: DateTime): JsValue = JodaWrites.JodaDateTimeWrites.writes(o)
}
```

**Do note however that the above doesn't include the old default writes which used epoch millis**. To ensure your migration doesn't break existing functionality, you probably want to hold the old defaults:

```
implicit val dateFormatDefault = new Format[DateTime] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DateTime] = JodaReads.DefaultJodaDateTimeReads.reads(json)
    override def writes(o: DateTime): JsValue = JodaDateTimeNumberWrites.writes(o)
}
```

This is because the old default in play-json used the millis (https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/jvm/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/EnvWrites.scala#L326-L328):

```
@deprecated("Include play-json-joda as a dependency and use JodaWrites.JodaDateNumberWrites", "2.6.0")
object DefaultJodaDateWrites extends Writes[DateTime] {
    def writes(d: DateTime): JsValue = JsNumber(d.getMillis)
}
```

And the the new default uses ISO8601 (https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/b4f812df628787e2d83131ceafbecb0d6d769704/play-json-joda/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JodaWrites.scala#L33-L35):

```
/**
 * Default Serializer LocalDate -> JsString(ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd))
 */
implicit object JodaDateTimeWrites extends Writes[DateTime] {
   def writes(d: DateTime): JsValue = JsString(d.toString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) time which is a wrapper of [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Then for a Json formatter you create this object

```
package formatters

import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import play.api.libs.json.{JsString, JsSuccess, JsValue, Format}

object DateTimeFormatter {
  private lazy val ISODateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
  private lazy val ISODateTimeParser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser

  implicit val dateTimeFormatter = new Format[DateTime] {
    def reads(j: JsValue) = JsSuccess(ISODateTimeParser.parseDateTime(j.as[String]))
    def writes(o: DateTime): JsValue = JsString(ISODateTimeFormatter.print(o))
  }
}
```

And in your companion object

```
object GeoArea {
  import formatters.DateTimeFormatter._
  implicit val geoAreaFormat = Json.format[GeoArea]
}
```